# Save state of file upload control in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using asp.net mvc framework. And trying to save state of controls after postback request. Values of simple controls (textbox etc...) can be easily get from request, but how to get value of file-input control in controller side from form.
Let form is as

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("method","controller",new{enctype="multiple/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name")
    <input type="file" name="f1" id="f1" />
}
```

And controller is as

```
[Httppost]
public ActionResult method()
{
   ViewBag.Name=Request["Name"]
  //here i have to get value of file-control i.e. path contained in it, to store in ViewBag
}
```

How to get value (i.e. path of file) from request.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the full original path to the file in most browsers, and you cannot set the value of an `input type=file` in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Make the action method take a `HttpPostedFileBase f1` as parameter; that object will represent the file, and it has a `SaveAs()` method that will let you save the uploaded file.